# Cheerio: preserve line breaks

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, cheerio

```html
<td align="center"><font face="Verdana"><font size=2><b> 3792&nbsp;R</b><br><font size=1>tp WHR3</font><br></font><font size=1><a href="http://www.lyngsat-maps.com/footprints/NSS-9-West-hemi.html">West hemi</a><br>39-40</font></td>
```

I want to get

1. 3792 R
2. tp WHR3
3. West hemi
4. 39-40

cheerio code -->

```js
$('td', td).text()
```

get text [ **3792 Rtp WHR3West hemi39-40**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target specific elements inside your `<td>` using CSS selectors:

```
const value1 = $('td font[face=Verdana] font[size=2] b').text() // 3792 R
const value2 =  $('td font[face=Verdana] font[size=2] font[size=1]').text() // tp WHR3
const value3 = $('td > font[size=1] a').text() // West hemi
const value4 = $('td > font[size=1]').text().substring(value3.length - 1) // 39-40
```

The last value you needed to retrieve was not contained inside a specific element so I retrieved the value of the parent element which contains the `value3` and `value4` and, subtracted the value of `value3` so what's remaining is `value4`